# Geometry stretching while posing, while it should be smooth

Tags: modeling, armature, sculpting, pose-mode, polycount

I'm pretty new to Blender and have just been getting into sculpting and posing. Now when I am giving my meshes more extreme poses, I start to see more big vertice artefacts where I suppose the model is stretching the most. It should be smooth, but it starts to look more blocky like in this example:

[image: EXAMPLES OF FACES STRETCHING]

[image]

[image]

While sculpting this model I used Quadremesher to make a Retopo and shrinkwrapped that with a multires to the highpoly sculpt. I assume I am seeing the problem that there is too little geometry to stretch it but I am curious if there is a way to work around this, or if I should work with a higher poly mesh in the first place.

Thank you.

Comment: That thing is creepy.

Comment: You do indeed seem to have too little geometry, and the workaround is indeed to add geometry to the mesh.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter thank you